# Counting records with 2 criteria s

Tags: mysql, sql, count

How do I count database records having 2 criteria.

Here is the pic:

[image]

I want to count posts which have condition 12 **&** 18 only. So after post 11 I should have the counter at value 1. Post 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 should not be counted since condition 12 & 18 don't show up.

To get the idea here is a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(post) from post_condition
where `condition`=18 AND  `condition`=12
```

But this is wrong, I tried with some sub-queries but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number that have both, then you can generate the matching posts using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT pc.post
      FROM post_condition pc
      WHERE pc.condition IN (12, 18)
      GROUP BY pc.post
      HAVING COUNT(pc.condition) = 2  -- assumes no duplicates
     ) t;
```

You can do this without a subquery, if you have a table of posts (which I suspect is true:

```
select count(*)
from posts p
where exists (select 1 from post_condition pc where pc.post = p.post and pc.condition = 12) and
      exists (select 1 from post_condition pc where pc.post = p.post and pc.condition = 18);
```

With an index on `post_condition(post, condition)`, this is likely to be the fastest method.  This would be slower only if many, many posts had no rows at all in `post_condition`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(post)
FROM table
WHERE condition IN (12, 18)
GROUP BY post
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(condition)) = 2;
```